# Using MVC, how should one handle communication between Views? Between Models?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, view, controller, components

Question number three in my quest to properly understand MVC *before* I implement it:

I have two cases in mind:

1. The primary application
   window needs to launch the
   preferences window. (One View
   invoking another View.)
2. The primary Model for an application
   needs to access a property
   in the preferences Model. (One Model
   accessing another Model.)

These questions are related in that they both involve communication across Model-View-Controller triplets, a topic that I haven't found much discussion of in my Googling.

The obvious way to fix this is to wrap everything in a top-level "application" object that handles transactions between Models and allows Controllers to invoke one another's methods.  I have seen this implemented, but I'm not convinced its a good idea.  I can also see possibilities involving Controllers observing more than one Model and responding to more than one View, but this seems like its going to become very cluttered and difficult to follow.

Suggestions on how best to implement this sort of cross-talk?  I feel like its a very obvious question, but I've been unable to find a well-documented solution.

On a broader note, if anyone has a link that shows typical approaches to these sorts of MVC issues, I would love to see it.  I haven't had much luck finding solid, non-trivial references.  Examples in Python would be lovely, but I'll gladly read anything.

**Edit 1**:

I see some pretty interesting things being said below and in general no-one seems to have a problem with the approach I've described.  It is already almost a lazy form of the FrontController design that Vincent is describing.  I certainly don't foresee any problems in implementing that pattern, however, it doesn't seem that anyone has really addressed the question in regards to communication amongst Models.  All the answers seem to be addressing communication among objects in a single Model.  I'm more interested in maintaining separate Models for separate components of the application, so that I'm not stuffing fifty state properties into a single Model class.  Should I be maintaining them as sub-Models instead?

Comment: We are talking about multiple classes in the model. The model refers to ALL the classes (components) that represent data and operations on data make up the model. These classes cooperate with each other.

Answer (score 4):

With respect to (1), views don't invoke other views.  They invoke controller actions that may result in other views being rendered.  In your case, the primary application window contains a user interface element (button, link) that invokes a controller action to display the preferences window.

With respect to (3), model components certainly could be related to one another.  This isn't unexpected nor to be avoided, necessarily.  For instance your Customer model may have an associated set of Orders.  It would be perfectly natural to access the customer's orders via a method in the Customer class.

You might want to take a look at the [MVC page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) on wikipedia for an overview.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider looking up the Front Controller design pattern.

> The Front Controller pattern defines a single component that is responsible for processing application requests. A front controller centralizes functions such as view selection, security, and templating, and applies them consistently across all pages or views. Consequently, when the behavior of these functions need to change, only a small part of the application needs to be changed: the controller and its helper classes.

This way all requests from the view goes to the FrontController who then decides which specific action (controller) to invoke. Sometimes, it could forward straight to another view as in your first case.

There is no problem with multiple objects in the model talking to each other. In fact that will be very common. The way I see it, all the objects in the Model act like one component to represent the data and operations on the data.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978723.aspx) article might help. And [this](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/patterns/FrontController.html) one.

Answer (score 0):

Model does not mean a single model object. The model is the subset of the entirety of your domain model which is directly related to the controller actions and the views in question.